# Is there any way to get the Video quality being played in YouTube androidPlayer API??

Tags: android-youtube-api

I am developing a you tube Client wherein I need to get the quality of the video being played when the video quality is in Auto.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly with I need to get the quality of the video? If you want to play off a specific video quality for instance hd1080, you can use the next code.

```js
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality("hd1080");
 }
```

Comment: I need not set any quality but i want to know how to get the quality of the video that is being played. Now, when you set the quality of the video in auto the quality changed on the bandwidth, So, i need to send the quality of the video being played to my server for every 5 sec.